# iOS hotspot + VPN behavior

Tags: iphone, vpn, tethering

I routinely use the Personal Hotspot feature on my iPhone.

Recently, I have set up a personal OpenVPN server (per [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)) to use with my phone. However, I don't *seem* to be able to use both at the same time - which I would like to do so any devices that connect to my phone's hotspot go through the VPN, too (for a few reasons - not least of which is to leverage the [pihole](https://antipaucity.com/2016/11/21/results-from-running-pi-hole-for-several-weeks) server I run for ad-blocking/etc).

Is this possible? Have I just done something incorrectly during VPN creation?

Comment: Same issue here. I wonder if it could be fixed by tinkering with the ios app’s advanced settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 11.2.6, if using the `Personal Hotspot` feature, any devices connected to the *hotspot* will show whatever the phone's public address is (eg from Verizon Wireless).

Interestingly, the *phone* will show that it is connected to the VPN.

If you run a web-based IP [check](https://ipv4.cf), the phone will display the VPN's address (as expected), but connected devices will have the non-VPN address.

For example, your *iPhone* might display `44.33.22.11`, because it's where the VPN is, but the laptop may show `77.55.33.11` because that's what the phone has for an underlying IP.

I don't know why this is - but it is what it is.